# Swift 5 which is the better usage of completition handler in uialertController?

Tags: swift, alert

A bit of clarification on closures and competition Hanlder about alerts. which is the better usage here? how, if I should, use "action" in second case? the result seems to be the same, it works, but I'd like to better understand WHY.

```
import UIKit

struct exapleStruct {
    var inHotel = true
}

class ViewController : UIViewController {

    var exapleStruct : exapleStruct!
    var detailTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let myAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add or Change value", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

        //firstExample
        let booleanChange = UIAlertAction(title: "change", style: .default, handler: self.handlerForBool)
        //second exampple how shoukld I use "action" ?? why is it there?
        let booleanChange2 = UIAlertAction(title: "change", style: .default) { (action) in
            print(self.exapleStruct.inHotel)
            self.detailTable.reloadData()
        }


        myAlertController.addAction(booleanChange)
        present(myAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

func handlerForBool(alertARgument: UIAlertAction!) {
    print(exapleStruct.inHotel)
    self.detailTable.reloadData()
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this

```
let booleanChange2 = UIAlertAction.init(title: "option1", style: .default, 
    handler: handlerForBool(alertARgument:))
let booleanChange3 = UIAlertAction.init(title: "option2", style: .default, 
    handler: handlerForBool(alertARgument:))
```

---

```
func handlerForBool(alertARgument: UIAlertAction!) {
    print(exapleStruct.inHotel)
    self.detailTable.reloadData()
}
```

is useful when you need same action for multiple alertActions , it's function reuseability

Comment: ok, your explanation is clear about this point, but ' { (action) in ' how should be used?

Comment: it's passed as reference that you can use such as using it's title or style if you need to otherwise it's useless

Comment: ok, so there is no usage other than "get" data from it right? thank you!

Comment: yes , in some cases also you may need to extend `UIAlertAction` class so attach more info